# No bootable device Acer Aspire es1-433-54xn

Tags: boot

When my acer laptop boots up I get: no bootable device.

The HDD in my laptop works as I have tested it.

I have enable F12 Boot menu in the bios and I changed boot mode to Legacy.

My boot order is correct. so my HDD is first.

Why do i still get no bootable device?? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

usually this means a defective disk or wrong boot mode.

A. defective disk- you say you have tested it- how?
B. wrong boot mode- you say "changed boot mode to Legacy"- have you tried the other options there? Have you changing this to UEFI?

Did you change anything in the hardware or software of your laptop prior to this?

MM

Comment: Yes I did test this disk in a desktop and i saw all the files. I can't see the disk in a external docking station. I have tried booting with UEFI and Legacy but no success. No software or hardware change has been done.